Fitting a Long Legend Within Mapview
I like what mapview outputs but can't really use it with with the burst option (seems to make legend interactive and zooms to group on click) as there's no way to adjust the scale of the legend. Is there a better mapping package to accomplish similar results but with legend scale formatting options? Or how do I accomplish this with mapview()?
sampled_stations |>
    sf::st_as_sf(coords = c(3:2),
                 crs = 4326) |>
    mapview::mapview(
        zcol = "station_names",
        col.regions = randomColors,
        map.types = "OpenStreetMap",
        burst = TRUE
    )

The data was grouped by station_name in sampled_stations. There are supposed to be 35 or so stations, so only a fraction of them fits within the fully expanded view. Everything looks great except that the legend isn't responsive to the actual dimensions of the map and or window.
The tibble input, sampled_stations:
sampled_stations tibble
The map output:
mapview example
